# preg_match_all, check + grab (+ remove)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm still quite a noob at regex.. but learning and trying ;)

I want to check if a string ends with a space + a year number between 1800 and 2100

If so, the function should grab that number (+ extract/remove it from the string)

Here is what I have so far.. does not work of course. But I must be close?

```
$thestring = 'Hello, the year is 1915';
$year = '';

if (preg_match_all('/ (18|19|20[0-9][0-9])$/', $thestring, $year)) {

  echo $thestring; // should not contain the year or last space anymore

  echo $year[0]; // ?? should be the extracted year (without the space)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
/ ((?:18|19|20)[0-9]{2})$/
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sC8pO9/2)

---

The problem with your expression is the nesting of alternation.  Think about when you learned about order of operations in algebra or even nesting multiple conditions, like: `if(A && (B || C)) {}`.

You're expression's capture group was looking for one of the following at the end of the string:

- `18`
- `19`
- `2000` - `2099`

I updated it to look for `18`, `19`, **OR** `20` *followed* by `00-99`.  Note that I used a non-capturing group `(?:...)` around the alternation, instead of a capturing group `(...)`.  If I didn't do this, you'd see we would have an [unecessary capture group](http://regex101.com/r/sC8pO9/3):

- 1990
- 19

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/ (1[89][0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2}|2100)$/
```

**Code:**

```
$thestring = 'Hello, the year is 1915';
if (preg_match('/ (1[89][0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2}|2100)$/', $thestring, $year)) {
  echo $year[1]; // should be the extracted year (without the space)    
}
```